# Spring Security Java Config Troubles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-security

I'm using Spring 4.1.6 and Spring Security 4.0.1

I'm trying to convert my Spring and Spring Security XML configurations over to Java config and have been stuck with the exception below for quite a while now...

```
 ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$1.postProcess(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:290)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:67)
    at csc.oceanlaw.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2885b2e.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80da63d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80da63d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a6cb227.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80da63d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 26 more
```

Here's my security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login"; 
    private static final String USER_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = 
            "select userName as username, password as password, 'true' as enabled " + 
            "from Users " +  
            "where (userName = ?)";
    private static final String AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = 
            "select userName as username, role as authority " + 
            "from UserRoles " +  
            "where userName = ?";

    private BasicDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http

            // Intercept-url config...
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/_a/**").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/_/**").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()

            // Login form config...
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/login?err=1")
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationHandler())
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .and()

            // Logout handling...
            .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutFilter())
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=1")
                .and()

            // Exception handling config...
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized")
                .authenticationEntryPoint(ajaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()

            .csrf()
                .disable();         

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USER_BY_USERNAME_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY)
                .passwordEncoder(md5PasswordEncoder())
                .dataSource(getDataSource());

    };

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityLogoutHandler logoutFilter() {
        return new SecurityLogoutHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint ajaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint(LOGIN_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder() {
        return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor defaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor() {
        return new DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        dataSource = new PersistenceConfig().dataSource();
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

}
```

It seems to point out the security config, however, it may be elsewhere in the config classes. So, below is the rest of config...

Main Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
        "myproject.model", 
        "myproject.web",
        "myproject.dao",
        "myproject.dao.jpa",
        "myproject.config"
    }
)
public class MainConfig {

    /**
     * Apache commons config bean.
     * @return {@link CompositeConfiguration}
     */
    @Bean(name="config")
    public CompositeConfiguration compositeConfiguration() throws ConfigurationException {

        PropertiesConfiguration textProps = null;
        PropertiesConfiguration validationProps = null;
        PropertiesConfiguration configProps = null;

        textProps = new PropertiesConfiguration("olsdmText.properties");
        textProps.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());

        validationProps = new PropertiesConfiguration("ValidationMessages.properties");
        validationProps.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());

        configProps = new PropertiesConfiguration("olsdmSettings.properties");
        configProps.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());

        CompositeConfiguration bean = new CompositeConfiguration();
        bean.addConfiguration(textProps);
        bean.addConfiguration(validationProps);
        bean.addConfiguration(configProps);
        bean.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(false);
        bean.setListDelimiter('|');

        return bean;

    }

}
```

Spring MVC config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration config;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/docs/**").addResourceLocations("/docs");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver bean = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

        // Apache Tiles view resolver...
        UrlBasedViewResolver tilesResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        tilesResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        tilesResolver.setOrder(0);
        viewResolvers.add(tilesResolver);

        // Default view resolver as a fallback. Allow view names to be served with just 
        // .jsp extension rather than a tiles id. This is primarily for AJAX calls that 
        // request a JSP resource...
        InternalResourceViewResolver defaultResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        defaultResolver.setPrefix(new String("/WEB-INF/views/"));
        defaultResolver.setSuffix(new String(".jsp"));
        defaultResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolvers.add(defaultResolver);

        bean.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);

        return bean;

    }

    /**
     * Sets Apache Tiles XML config file location.
     * @return {@link TilesConfigurer}
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfig() {
        TilesConfigurer bean = new TilesConfigurer();
        String[] definitions = {"/WEB-INF/views/tiles/config/tiles-config.xml"};
        bean.setDefinitions(definitions);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordGen passwordGen() {
        return new PasswordGen();
    }

    @Bean
    public Encrypt encrypt() {
        return new Encrypt();
    }

}
```

Datasource/JPA config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:olsdmSettings.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.databaseUrl}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.userName}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${jdbc.passWord}")
    private String passWord;

    @Value("${jdbc.validationQuery}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Value("${jdbc.testWhileIdle}")
    private boolean testWhileIdle;

    @Value("${jdbc.maxTotal}")
    private int maxTotal;

    @Value("${jdbc.maxIdle}")
    private int maxIdle;

    @Value("${jdbc.maxWailMillis}")
    private int maxWailMillis;

    /**
     * Sets datasource configuration.
     * @return {@link BasicDataSource}
     */
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource bean = new BasicDataSource();
        bean.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        bean.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        bean.setUsername(userName);
        bean.setPassword(passWord);
        bean.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        bean.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
        bean.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
        bean.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        bean.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWailMillis);

        return bean;

    }

    /**
     * Sets application {@link LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean}
     * @return {@link LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean}
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return bean;

    }

    /**
     * Sets application {@link JpaTransactionManager}
     * @return {@link JpaTransactionManager}

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager bean = new JpaTransactionManager();
        bean.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) emf());

        return bean;

    } */

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                emf().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Sets application {@link Jaxb2Marshaller}
     * @return {@link Jaxb2Marshaller}
     */
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {

        Jaxb2Marshaller bean = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        bean.setPackagesToScan(new String("myproject.model"));

        return bean;

    }

    //To resolve ${} in @Value
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

WebApplicationIntializer implementation:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "myproject.config";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/*";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = 
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);

    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm getting the same error when translating over to a java config. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not ever resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest Spring Security? Quite a few initialization issues have been fixed since Security 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

public static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{
            WebMVCConfig.class,
            PersistenceConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/*","/*"};
}

@Override
protected javax.servlet.Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    final CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    encodingFilter.setEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
    encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    final OpenSessionInViewFilter openSessionInViewFilter = new OpenSessionInViewFilter();
    return new Filter[] { encodingFilter, openSessionInViewFilter };
}



@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    registerListener(servletContext);
}

private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    RequestContextListener requestContextListener = new RequestContextListener();
    servletContext.addListener(requestContextListener);
}}
```

needs to @Override Class[] getRootConfigClasses method.that will make you configurer class as a configurer bean.so you can use @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration in you configclass code.
hope this can help!
like this:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{
            WebMVCConfig.class,
            PersistenceConfig.class};
}
```